# Proper way to remove file extensions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web, seo

What is the proper way to have URLs without file extensions on an Apache web server?  Currently I'm using this implementation in an .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

However, some URLs have a trailing / while others don't and I'm not sure why.  I'd prefer it with a trailing / but does it make a difference?  Also, if enter 'about.php' how can I get it to go to 'about' instead?  drexel.edu has the file structure I'm looking to replicate, but I'm not sure how they do it.

Also, how does this affect SEO?  Will search engines count pages like 'about.php' and 'about' as two separate duplicate pages or do they know it's the same thing without me having to do anything extra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these two rules for effectively removing `.php` extension and taking care of SEO rankings:

```
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /file.php to /file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# To internally redirect /file OR file/ to /file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Due to first 301 redirection search engines will not cache `/file.php` page and only `/file` will be cached in search results.

Comment: It seems like that significantly increase the time it takes to load a page now.

Comment: Page loading time is not related to rewrite rules, besides these are rules from a live website of mine. You should clear your browser cache completely and then test.

Comment: Perhaps it was just the server being slow at the time; it seems fine now.  Thank you so much!